# Finding minimum and maximum value for each row, excluding NaN values

Tags: python, numpy, max, minimum

I have a code that plots multiple wind speed values during a day at 50 different altitudes.  I'm trying to program it where it gives me the minimum and maximum values at each different altitude so I can see the minimum and maximum winds experienced during the day.

I've tried `np.min(wind_speed, axis=0)` but this is giving me nan.  I have a line that reads bad values of wind speed as nan.  How would I able to avoid getting the nan value and getting the actual minimum and maximum value occurring during the day?

Comment: use `np.nanmin(wind_speed, axis=0)` this will ignore `NaN` values

Comment: how is the data organized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ignore the `NaN` values use [`nanmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html#numpy.nanmin) and the analagous [`nanmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html#numpy.nanmax):

```
npnanmin(wind_speed, axis=0)
npnanmax(wind_speed, axis=0)
```

This will ignore the `NaN` values as desired

Example:

```
In [93]:
wind_speed = np.array([234,np.NaN,343, np.NaN])
wind_speed

Out[93]:
array([ 234.,   nan,  343.,   nan])

In [94]:
print(np.nanmin(wind_speed, axis=0), np.nanmax(wind_speed, axis=0))
234.0 343.0
```